# создание нового ListPreference из выборки arraylist

Tags: java, android

может не совсем точно звучит заголовок. суть вот в чем. есть некий List(Map), структура которого примерно такая

```
id=0; title="нулевой уровень"; parent=null
id=1; title="уровень 0.1"; parent=0
id=11; title="нулевой уровень 1"; parent=null
id=111; title="уровень 1.0"; parent=11
id=1111; title="нулевой уровень"; parent=111
```

грубо говоря, это каталог товаров с категориями. нужно как то сделать поочередный выбор категорий. из-за моего малого опыта в java мой подход к этому вопросу выливается в распухший метод перебора всего списка и добавления кучи массивов...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте 2-е коллекции: одна хранит название категорий, другая хранит название товаров. Например, так вы заполняете лист корневой:

```
public someClass {
public ArrayList initManufList() {
    ManufacturerList.add("Audi");
    ManufacturerList.add("Skoda");
    ManufacturerList.add("Volkswagen");
    return ManufacturerList;
}
// инициализируем корневой лист
public ArrayList initModelList(String str){
    if(str.equals("Audi"))
        return initAudiList();
    else if (str.equals("Skoda"))
        return initSkodaList();
    else if (str.equals("Volkswagen"))
        return initVolkswagenList();
    return null;
} // на основе корня выбираете дочерние элементы
private ArrayList initAudiList(){
    AudiList.add("A1");
    AudiList.add("A2");
    AudiList.add("A3");
    AudiList.add("A4");
    return AudiList;
}}
```

Ну а дальше логика, как привязать дочерние элементы к родительским.